# TYPO3 v12 - Using RTE in own Backend Module does not work anymore

Tags: fluid, extbase, typo3-12.x

In v11 I used JS (`require(['ckeditor'], function (CKEDITOR) { ... }`) to init the CKEditor in my backend form. But after my upgrade to v12 the whole thing does not work anymore.

I searched the whole TYPO3 code for an example, but they totally changed the concept. I only found the code (RichTextElement.php), which created the Formfields defined in the TCA, but I use extbase/fluid for my module. And for this I didn't found any example.

Can anybody help me?